# Is it possible to run cucumber steps conditionally in the same scenario?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, cucumber

So basically I want to be able to use the same feature file and run two separate tests, one tagged with @mobile and the other with @desktop. This way I don't have to duplicate another feature file for just a single step.

So something like this:

```
Scenario: Steps will run conditionally if tagged
  Given user is logged in
  @mobile
  When user clicks "logout link on mobile"
  @desktop
  When user clicks "logout link on desktop"
  Then user will be logged out
```

When I run the mobile test (I will have @~desktop in the config file), I want it to ignore the @desktop step and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Scenario Outline` and put in two `Examples` tables and tag them. Use the tag you want in the filter to run your test. The tag you put in will be run other will be ignored.

```
Scenario Outline: Steps will run conditionally if tagged
  Given user is logged in
  When user clicks <link>
  Then user will be logged out

@mobile
Examples: 
| link |
| logout link on mobile |

@desktop
Examples:
| link |
| logout link on desktop |
```

Answer (score 1):

There's one more approach you can try for this case -

Keep a single step in Cucumber like this:

```
When user clicks logout link
Then user will be logged out
```

Within the code for this step, add an if condition where you can call either mobile or desktop related function based on the flag you pass from config file?

Comment: Yes, that seems to the most feasible route for what I'm trying to accomplish. I'll see if I can work it inside the step.